# Computing $n$-th term Holonomic Sequence in $O(\log(n))$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $a_n$ be the $n$-th term of this sequence:

$1, 2, 3, 16, 35, 106, 287, 820, 2319, 6634, 19019, 54770, 158171, 458056, 1329551, 3867076, 11267855, 32884954, 96111899, 281267470, 824083259, 2417052268, 7096175855, 20852160526, 61324675775, 180488550376, 531581605827, 1566658748080, 4620016882739, 13632008884202, 40244583972479, 118869908099284, 351269331261503, 1038485484981946, 3071436936035147, 9087694941680846,...$

$a_1=1, a_2=2, a_3=3, a_4=16$ and so on (Offset could be $0$ or $1$).

Mathematica returns the following formula for $a_n$:

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1, 2, 3, 16, 35, 106, 287, 820, 2319, 6634, 19019, 54770, 158171, 458056, 1329551, 3867076, 11267855, 32884954, 96111899, 281267470, 824083259, 2417052268, 7096175855, 20852160526, 61324675775, 180488550376, 531581605827, 1566658748080, 4620016882739, 13632008884202, 40244583972479}, n]

DifferenceRoot[Function[{y, n}, {(-6-3n)y[n] + (-11-5n)y[1+n] + (-2-n)y[2+n] + (3+n)y[3+n] == 0, y[1] == 1, y[2] == 2, y[3] == 3, y[4] == 16, y[5] == 35}]]
```

So the sequence is not a linear recurrence relation.

Is there any easy way to compute $a_n$ in $O(\log(n))$ time? similar to how [recurrence relations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1i9xw7QjzHw) would be computed?

More specifically, I'm trying to compute

$a_n \pmod n$ for some very large (probable prime) index $n$:

If $p$ is prime, then $a_p \equiv 0 \pmod p$

I think this is one of many special cases of holonomic sequences, but I'm not sure if they can be computed in a reasonable amount of time. Thanks for help!

Comment: Where does this sequence come from? The first $5$ terms are already not in the OEIS.

Comment: Maybe, there are useful relations as in the case of Fibonacci-numbers.